# How much information that I can fetch from my iPhone programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, device

How much information I can get about my iPhone programmatically.

Like ESN, IME ID, phone equipment number etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)